# Run script when password is changed

Tags: linux, debian, authentication, users, passwd

Is there any way to run a custom command when `passwd` is executed?
I'm creating a server GUI, and I want to tie the app users with the system users,
And, I don't want to use just plain PAM Auth.
So I want to run a script that will receive the user and password, and send it to the Mysql Server.
Actually now that I'm writing it out, it seems some what of a security issue.
Regardless, Is this possible?

Comment: May be using parameter expose_authtok in pam_exec:
**auth required   pam_exec.so expose_authtok your_script**

Answer (score 1):

You can detect if someone runs `passwd` using `inotifywait`, but as far as I know, you can't control its behaviour this way.

On your own server however, you can replace the real `passwd` program with your script, which invokes the real `passwd` program then. This may imply several security risks, so I wouldn't do that, and I wouldn't even try to list all the risks. Still if you feel like doing such thing, an `expect` script like this could work as a replacement:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout -1
set new_passwd ""

log_user 0
spawn /usr/bin/passwd.real
log_user 1

stty -echo
expect {
    -re "current.*password" {
        expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
        send "$expect_out(1,string)\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re "new.*password:" {
        expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
        set new_passwd $expect_out(1,string)
        send "$new_passwd\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    -re "passwd:.*unchanged" {
        set new_passwd ""
        interact
    }
    -re "passwd:.*updated successfully" {
        interact
    }
}
stty echo

if { $new_passwd != "" } {
    send_user "New password for user '$env(USER)'/'$env(LOGNAME)': $new_passwd\n"
    #system my_password_manipulation_script.sh $env(USER) $env(LOGNAME) $new_passwd
}
```

After renaming `passwd` to `passwd.real`, you would place this script into `/usr/bin/passwd` and give it normal running permission (0755). Suid bit is not necessary (and would be another security issue), as this script is just a frontend to the real `passwd` program.

The script works on Debian Jessie (8.4), on other systems you may have to adjust the matching keywords (current.*password, new.*password, etc). Also you would comment out the last send_user line, and uncomment the system call, where you actually propagate the password.

Once again: try to consider all the security implications, before you do  this! Also, your users should probably know, that you may be able to get their passwords unencrypted. Maybe it would be nicer, if you saved this script as eg. `mypasswd` (and it would spawn `passwd` then), and asked your users to change password using `mypasswd`. This would make it clear, that they're not using the original `passwd`.